# PdfBox-Android adding page text overlay

Tags: java, android, pdfbox

Stuck with PDFBox-Android, pdfbox-android:1.8.9.0

I load first page of a pdf file, write text in and import this page to a new page of a final document.

Problem is when create new pages, it use last page which contain previous text...
So, first page is ok, but nexts have texts superposed..

```
private File writeReport() {
    File fileSource = new File(getActivity().getApplicationContext().getExternalCacheDir(), "fileSource.pdf");

    // get file model in assets
    InputStream inputAsset = null;
    try {
        inputAsset = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getResources().getAssets().open("file_model.pdf");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // copy file model in fileSource
    try {
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
        int length = 0;

        while ((length = inputAsset.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        outputStream.close();
        inputAsset.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.print("Copy assets : IOException" + e.getMessage());
    }

    File fileTarget = new File(getActivity().getApplicationContext().getCacheDir(), "fileTarget.pdf");


    try {
        PDFBoxResourceLoader.init(getActivity().getApplicationContext());       // init lib

        PDDocument documentSource = PDDocument.load(fileSource);
        PDDocument documentTarget = new PDDocument();

        // iteration == a new page
        for(int i=0 ; i < 3 ; i++)
        {
            PDPage page = documentSource.getDocumentCatalog().getPages().get(0);
            PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(documentSource, page, true, true);

            PDFont font1 = PDType1Font.HELVETICA;

            float startY = page.getMediaBox().getUpperRightY();
            float factor = 2.83f;

            page.getStream();

            // add text
            contentStream.beginText();
            contentStream.setFont(font1, 10);
            contentStream.newLineAtOffset(factor * 60, startY - (factor * 53));
            contentStream.showText("test text" + i);
            contentStream.endText();

            contentStream.close();

            // import source page to output file->  Problem here ! new page contain old overlay text... 
            documentTarget.importPage(page);
        }
        documentTarget.save(fileTarget);
        documentTarget.close();
        documentSource.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return fileTarget;
}
```

Is there a way to have fresh page at every iteration ?
Thanks !

Comment: "it use last page which contain previous text" last page of source or of destination page? "previous text" of what? Of the previous iteration? If so, then it is as intended, as you are modifying the same page PDPage object.

Comment: The better solution (please test this first) would be to import the page first, get the return PDPage (it is now a new object), and to add the extra content stream using that one as parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your reply !
- It use last _destination_ page  which contain text _of the last iteration.
I was thinking PDPage is newly created at every iteration besause of declaration in the loop...
- And I've tried your solution but without success : same result...

Comment: Ok, so what you should try is: move "documentTarget.importPage(page);" below the "getDocumentCatalog" line, and change it into "page = documentTarget.importPage(page);" then test your application again.

Comment: Ho yeah !! It's not the final result i need but there is no more superpositions !!
I have to try to understand now !
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you reused the same PDPage object, which resulted in the effect that it contained the text of the previous iteration. Solution: use the result of

```
documentTarget.importPage(page)
```

and work with that one. Because that is a new PDPage object with everything cloned. So your new code will be like this:

```
    // iteration == a new page
    for(int i=0 ; i < 3 ; i++)
    {
        PDPage page = documentSource.getDocumentCatalog().getPages().get(0);
        page = documentTarget.importPage(page); // this is now a new PDPage object
        PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(documentSource, page, true, true);

        PDFont font1 = PDType1Font.HELVETICA;

        float startY = page.getMediaBox().getUpperRightY();
        float factor = 2.83f;

        page.getStream();

        // add text
        contentStream.beginText();
        contentStream.setFont(font1, 10);
        contentStream.newLineAtOffset(factor * 60, startY - (factor * 53));
        contentStream.showText("test text" + i);
        contentStream.endText();

        contentStream.close();            
    }
```